# Best way to detect multiple collisions in a component based architecture (Unity)

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine

Let's say we have a player and multiple enemies and we need to detect every player/enemy/debris collision.
Since I'm not familiar with the component based approach, the best I came up with is this :
Add a EnemyContact script component to each player/enemy/debris entity. Each of these entities also have an EntityController component.

```
//EnemyContact.cs
public void TakeDamage(float damage)(); //which makes the entity absorbe the given damage, explode if necessary and do all the collision stuff
```

and then

```
//EntityController.cs 
public damage;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision entity)  //Make the entity collided with do its collision operations
{
   entity.GetComponent<EnemyContact>().TakeDamage(damage);
}
//--
```

I dont think that's the best way to do it and any idea to improve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, at least it sounds similar to what I've done. Although I would make the following changes:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision entity)
{
    if (entity.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy")) {
        entity.GetComponent<EnemyContact>().TakeDamage(damage);
    }
}
```

That way you don't get a `NullReferenceException` if `entity` doesn't have an `EnemyContact` script attached.

Of course, depending on your situation, you could make the `EnemyContact` more generic (so it would encapsulate all enemy behavior) or have an `EnemyController` script or something.

Comment: Ok, i guess that method will have to do.Thank you.